# Does my meaning come across clearly in this sentence?

Tags: word-order

‘He acknowledged, however, that this was probably nothing more than a self serving thought that belonged to him alone.’

Context: ‘He’ has just guessed (not aloud) what the body language of the person he’s watching is trying to convey in a way that makes it seem as if she spoke, though she didn’t. (Like this: She scratched her head, as if to say, ‘What on Earth are you talking about?’.) His guess at the meaning behind her body language would, if correct, please him, but he doesn’t think he’s correct or that anyone else who saw it interpreted it in the same way.

My question: I’m unsure whether or not I’ve correctly placed ‘self serving’ in this sentence. I think it might not be clear that I’m trying to say the thought was self serving to him and not anyone else. If it could be misunderstood this way, can someone let me know how to fix it?

Comment: As a standalone sentence, _self serving_ (should it be hyphenated?) and _that belonged to him alone_ seem a little ... almost tautologous. But perhaps context rectifies this. But style issues are off-topic here; try the budding Byrons over on Literature. / Self-serving will almost always be taken as referring to the most likely referent (sans context, here 'he' ... and 'that belonged to him alone' at least nails this reading).

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth: Haha, budding Byrons. Thanks, I’ll check out the SE. And thank you for your input.